# Why Cant I Mention In Message (It Shows The Id)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Why can't I mention the user? (It shows the ID) Here is my code:

```py
async def bday(message, *args):
    bdb = ""
    for arg in args:
        bdb = bdb + "" + arg
        bdb = bdb.capitalize()
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="We wish **" + bdb + "** A Happy Birthday!!",
        description="""
Here's The Birthday Song: 
* Happy Birthday To You...*
* Happy Birthday To You...*
* May God Bless You...*
* Happy Birthday Dear **""" +bdb+ """**...*
* Happy Birthday To You...*""",
        url="",
        color=0xffffff
    )
    await message.send(embed=embed)
```

(That's not my name and id)

This is the message:  `We wish <@!696969696969> A Happy Birthday!! Here's The Birthday Song:  Happy Birthday To You...  Happy Birthday To You...  May God Bless You...  Happy Birthday Dear @MyName...  Happy Birthday To You...`

Comment: Welcome to Stack! Sadly, you can't mention users in the title of an embed.

Answer (score 1):

if its a command,you can use

```
ctx.author.mention
#this will mention the user that did the command
```

If its a command but you choose

```
async def bday(ctx, member:discord.Member)
member.mention
```

Comment: but i want to mention anyone and not myself. thats why i have args and not author mention thing